# How to replace Blender's Drive Coupling?

Tags: repair, kitchens, appliances

I am in need to replace the drive coupling of a blender, Breville BBL605.
The drive coupling looks some thing like this : 
[image]
I watched a video on youtube for a similar looking blender :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTH3g-jVUtg

From the video, it doesn't look *exactly* like the drive coupling on the Breville and also I have no idea how the guy figured it was a left handed thread. The presenter also doesn't show if the drive spins clockwise and anti-clockwise freely as the Breville's does. Since the Breville's drive coupling freely spins in both directions, I *think* this videos approach may not work.

How can I go about replacing the drive coupling of this blender ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because “questions regarding small appliances” are off-topic per the help center.

Answer (score 1):

If it is press fit then you need to just pull *hard*.

If it is screwed then you need to lock the shaft somehow and then turn the coupling in the same direction as it normally turns when it blends. Locking the shaft down may require some disassembly to get access to it.

If you have the replacement ready you can look where the shaft connects to see which it is.

Comment: How do I find out if its press fit or if its screwed ?